# How to display a dice rolled value to all online user at a time?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

In action script Adobe flash, I created a board game which roll a dice. Although it is a multi-player game & played online, if Player1 roll the dice the rolling action and its "value should be visible to other players" (i.e., Player2, Player3, Player4). How to achieve that?

Using php at server end.
Please give some suggestions.

Any Help here?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not use flash. So, if flash has push ability, this would likely change. Standard web architecture is pull only. Each client will pull data from the server when the client wants to pull data. So, to keep things in order, the server has to deliver all pertinent actions in order. How is it done? You timestamp each action. Then, the client says "Give me all actions after #" where # is a timestamp. The server sends all new actions. The client handles them and then says "Give me all actions after #" where # is the new timestamp. So, your PHP script is really just dumping a log of activity.

Comment: I do not know as3 so can not help with code. However I guess all the players have to "long poll" the server when using apache. If you use Nginx instead of apache then there are other ways (not sure, have not used that yet myself). The php will then simply check in the database for the last throw and display this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713305/long-polling-with-nginx-advice-and-clarification. However long-polling uses a lot of resources. So if you have a lot of different players constantly polling the server it might drag your server down. I would really use NGinx in this case.

Comment: For AS3,   you'll want to use sockets or Adobe Media Server Shared Objects.  Web search to find tutorials.

Comment: You can do it using php, xml, and timer in as3.  The game can "exist" on the server.  You can use timers to constantly load a tiny xml that gives the game state.  Once an event happens, the players can load the event xml.  The dice rolling, score, anything shared, is in php.

Answer (score 2):

This an implentation issue, rather than specific to any particular language. The Observer Design pattern would be ideal for your situation.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern):

> The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods.

So in this case, your "Observers" are your players, which you would register with the "Subject". Whenever an Observer changes its state (rolls the dice), the Subject is notified, and then all other Observers are notified as well.

How you store the data isn't really important here. As long as the Observer notifies the Subject that it has rolled the dice, the Subject can then update all Observers registered with it.

You could store/retrieve the data from a database table. You then only have to write to it as each player makes their move, and read from it when the Subject is notified to update all the Observers of the move.

So each player could have their own *id*, which would be your primary table key, and when one of them makes a move, the table is updated. You'll need a way of notifying your game to know the table has been updated. Writing it to an xml file the game constantly checks would be one way, and it would update the players when the xml data changes.

There's all sorts of ways you can implement the pattern, but you'll find it much easier to figure out using the Observer pattern.